# For a file uploader, would you choose SWFUpload or Plupload?

Tags: file, file-upload, swfupload, plupload

I have googled for the past hour about that but couldn't find a good comparison.

I know Plupload has many platforms to fall back on like HTML5 Gears, Silverlight, Flash and
SWF is just flash.

What I want to do is a simple multi file (images only) upload that will display the uploaded images on the same page without refreshing.

I originally wanted to use an Ajax File uploader but I am worried about compatibility problems, where as Flash seems to be all the same across browsers.

Please let me know if you have any suggestion.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Definitely choose plupload especially because the graceful fallback mechanism. It will go for HTML5 per default, which is undoubted the best choice if available; and fall back to other configured, so called "runtimes".

Be aware that plupload only provides an API. You have to built your appropriate user interface on your own, however plupload also brings some JQuery Widgets.